# RxJava2: .andThen() called even though first Completable emitted error

Tags: android, mockito, rx-java, rx-java2

I have 2 completables in a method, like:

```
completable1.doSomething()
    .andThen(completable2.doSomethingElse())
```

And I want to test it, by using Mockito and returning error in the first completable. Here is my original method:

```
 public Completable updateQuestion(Question question){
    return gameRepositoryType.updateQuestion(question)
            .andThen(gameRepositoryType.getGameById(question.getqId())
                    .map(GAME_MAPPER)
                    .flatMapCompletable(gameRepositoryType::updateGame))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

And here is my test:

```
@Test
public void updateQuestionError(){
    when(gameRepositoryType.updateQuestion(question)).thenReturn(Completable.error(error));
    when(question.getqId()).thenReturn(FAKE_QID);
    when(gameRepositoryType.getGameById(FAKE_QID)).thenReturn(Single.just(game));
    when(gameRepositoryType.updateGame(game)).thenReturn(Completable.complete());

    interactor.updateQuestion(question)
            .test()
            .assertNotComplete()
            .assertError(error);

    verify(gameRepositoryType).updateQuestion(question);       //this is called in test
    verify(question,never()).getqId();                         //this is called in test
    verify(gameRepositoryType,never()).getGameById(FAKE_QID);  //this is called in test
    verify(gameRepositoryType,never()).updateGame(game);       //this is NEVER called in test
}
```

In my verifications at the end of the test method, I am expecting after the first completable emitts an error, the 3 last verifications should run with success, i.e the 3 last `verify()` should never be called.

However I can see that all methods are called even though `gameRepositoryType.updateQuestion(question)` emitts error. Why is that?

Shouldn't `andThen()` never be called if the first completable emitts error?

Comment: if you want the code above to work, you would have to change this line to:
`when(gameRepositoryType.updateQuestion(question)).thenThrow(error);` so it would fail to build the chain and the other methods won't be executed. as you are returning a Completable.error, the whole chain and all operators will be executed

Comment: @Gustavo Thanks for the help. I am wondering if there is some way to design the chain so that the rest of the chain is not executed in case that updateQuestion() throws error/returns completable.error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
completable1.doSomething()
    .andThen(completable2.doSomethingElse())
```

> Shouldn't andThen() never be called if the first completable emitts error?

`andThen` will always call `completable2.doSomethingElse()` to build the stream, but the Completable that is returned by it will never be subscribed to.

You can test it this way:

```java
when(completable1.doSomething()).thenReturn(Completable.error(error));

CompletableSubject completableSubject = CompletableSubject.create();
when(completable2.doSomethingElse()).thenReturn(completableSubject);


TestObserver testObserver = completable1.doSomething()
    .andThen(completable2.doSomethingElse()).test();

// Verify that completable2.doSomethingElse() was never subscribed to:
assertFalse(completableSubject.hasObservers());

testObserver
    .assertError(error)
    .assertNotComplete();
```

Edit: for further clarification:

Given your methods are defined like this:

```java
private Completable updateQuestion(Question question) {
    System.out.println("prints when the updateQuestion is called");
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        System.out.println("prints when updateQuestion is subscribed to");
        database.updateQuestion(question);
    });
}

private Completable updateGame() {
    System.out.println("prints when the updateGame is called");
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        System.out.println("prints when updateGame is subscribed to");
        database.updateGame();
    });
}
```

Suppose you call:

```
updateQuestion(question)
    .andThen(updateGame())
    .subscribe();
```

And `database.updateQuestion(question);` throws an error.

Then your log output would be:

```
prints when the updateQuestion is called
prints when the updateGame is called
prints when updateQuestion is subscribed to
>> error
```

and `database.updateGame();` will never be executed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that if (in non-test case/real case) `completable2.doSomethingElse()` will be called but ignored if `completable1.doSomething()` emitts error? Or is my stream wrong? Because the points is that completable2 should not be called in case that completable1 emitts error

Comment: not sure if "ignored" is the correct way of saying it, `completable2.doSomethingElse()` is being called in the chain and it is expected to return a Completable, that once it is subscribed to, will complete or emit error. In your example, the question shouldn't be updated when `updateQuestion` is called, but a Completable should be returned that when subscribed to, will update the question. You can achieve this with operators like [fromAction](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromAction-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) or defer

Comment: e.g.: ```public Completable updateQuestion(Question question) { Completable.fromAction({ // call database here } ) }```

Comment: Ok, so if `updateQuestion(Question question)` returns Completable.error() (which is first in the stream) will the rest of stream be aborted? Or will andThen(....) still be called and perform its work? My goal is that if `updateQuestion()` returns a Completable.error() the rest of the stream should not run its course.

Comment: I updated the answer in order to add code to explain better

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your help, I understand the logic in my code better now.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody stuck with the same issue try to `defer` the second Completable.

abstract example:

```
repo.executeCompletable1()
                .andThen(
                    Completable.defer {
                        repo.executeCompletable2()
                    }
                )
```